# Can I ignore failed package installation statuses?

Tags: debian, package-management

I've upgraded a package with `apt-get upgrade` on debian 6.  The upgrade failed, but I understand why (one of the init scripts had been customised, and the upgrade script was attempting to use the old one when restarting the service).

If I run `dpkg -l` the package is showing is status as `iF` (failed).

Can I ignore this failed status if I believe the rest of the installation went OK, or are there other side effects to the package status?

Comment: No, you shouldn't ignore this, and the package system will probably not let you. You should fix the problem. The usual way of resolving these things is `apt-get -f install`, but it sounds like it may not help you in this case. It will probably just remove the offending package.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - thanks - can you explain what you mean by the package system not letting me? It seems the package is working ok (and the app is reporting the updated version number)

Comment: Well, my experience has been that the Debian packaging system (specifically, apt and friends) is quite fussy about everything being ok before permitting further action, and with good reason - in general you want everything 100% ok. Have you tried for example installing or removing another package? Does your system let you? As far as resolving your actual error, you haven't given enough details to make any specific suggestions, but I'm sure it is possible, and probably not difficult.